# Getting a UDT from a LongPtr in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, winapi

I want to get a UDT that is kept as a pointer in the user data associated with a subclassed window.
The UDT is declared as:

```
Type ID
 nPID As long
 hDefProc As LongPtr
End Type

Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLongPtr Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As LongPtr
```

`GetWindowLongPtr()` returns a LongPtr, and I can't seem to dereference that

Inside my subclassed WindowProc I'm trying to access it like this

```
Dim pID As ID
pID = GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA) '<- Err: Type mismatch
```

Is there a way to dereference this in vb6? If not, what are my alternatives to store data in a sub-classed windowclass?

- **EDIT :**

I did a poor job at explaining. The problem I'm having boils down to this. I can't allocate an UDT on the heap and dereference it after: This is the full code:

```
Type IDT
    id As Long
    SomeOther As Long
End Type

Public Const HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE = &H1
Public Const HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY = &H8

Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr)
Declare PtrSafe Function HeapAlloc Lib "kernel32" Alias "HeapAlloc" (ByVal hHeap As LongPtr, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Declare PtrSafe Function GetProcessHeap Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetProcessHeap" () As LongPtr

Sub main()
   Dim SourceIDT As IDT
   Dim HeapIDT As LongPtr
   Dim TestIDT As IDT

   SourceIDT.id = 1234
   Debug.Print "SourceIDT.id = " & SourceIDT.id ' returns 1234

   HeapIDT = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE or HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, LenB(SourceIDT))
   CopyMemory ByVal HeapIDT, VarPtr(SourceIDT), LenB(SourceIDT)

   CopyMemory VarPtr(TestIDT), ByVal HeapIDT, LenB(SourceIDT)
   Debug.Print "TestIDT.id = " & TestIDT.id ' expected 1234, but getting 0
   ' to do: free
End Sub
```

"Dereferencing" it like that always yields garbage or zero. What am I doing wrong? It's a VBA6 macro in Excel x86 if that matters.

Comment: `Private|Public Type ID` does not declare an "object" or a class but an UDT which will not work in your case. You would need an instance of a real class to store pointer to.

Comment: You're right. My bad. I'm trying to pass an UDT as a pointer.

Comment: @ptim But could you use a class instead of a UDT?

Comment: @Brian I probably could, I haven't tried that to be honest. Using an UDT seemed easier at the time because I don't have to deal with any reference counting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `ByVal` for the `CopyMemory` parameter, like:

```
Sub main()
   Dim SourceIDT As IDT
   Dim TestIDT As IDT

   SourceIDT.id = 1234
   Debug.Print "SourceIDT.id = " & SourceIDT.id ' returns 1234

   CopyMemory ByVal TestIDT, ByVal SourceIDT, LenB(SourceIDT)
   Debug.Print "TestIDT.id = " & TestIDT.id ' get 1234
   ' to do: free
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't understand why, but that works like a charm, thanks a lot!

Comment: Also note that, you need to use `HeapFree` to release the heap, otherwise it will cause memory leak. Or you don’t have to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign it to the element of ID that has a matching type, not the ID itself. Like

```
pID.hDefProc = GetWindowLongPtr(Application.hwnd, -21)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That would work, but I'm trying to store more than just one variable in the UserData, that's why `GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, -21)` points to an object that contains all variables I'm going to need. 
I set it using `Call SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, -21, VarPtr(pID)`

Comment: You are using `VarPtr()` to convert the memory address of an object into a `LongPtr`. VB doesn’t have any functions to do the inverse of that, to get an object reference back out of a `LongPtr`. But you can write some functions. See [Dereferencing Pointers sans CopyMemory](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?707879-VB6-Dereferencing-Pointers-sans-CopyMemory) for examples (particularly `GetObjFromPtr()`).

Comment: That was really helpful, thanks. However, I couldn't get those examples to work, so I tried CopyMemory, which doesn't seem to work either. I edited the OP with my code. Is there something I'm missing here?